# SQL Server 2008 R2 connectivity issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, database-connection

We have Installed SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer edition, for testing purpose we have put that machine as Local server.

When we try to connect from other machines Visual studio 2010 or from SQL Server Management studio, it works fine.

But after some time suddenly the connection is not working. (might be because of 6 users are trying to use the sql server at the same time). As per setting it is set as unlimited access.

If we restart the machine it works fine again for some hours then again we face this problem

Anyone have any idea why it is happening this way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is only connection to SQL Server instance not working? Can you still ping the machine hosting it?

Comment: What error messages are you receiving when the connection isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be sure you close your connections when you open them. If you open connections to the database and never close them - eventually you'll run out of them and the server will have to be restarted. Determine what is not disposing the connections or what isn't using connection pooling.

Comment: The connections are properly disposed. It seems like some setting or firewall issue. Earlier when we had SQL server 2008 Enteriprise verison in the server it worked fine. But when we made SQL Server 2008 Developer edition in one of our programmers machine as server this issue got raised. So i dont think it is code issue, some thing to do with setting or firewall etc